# Binding Commands Without Using the DataContext [silverlight+prism]

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, binding, prism, command

Hello I have a problem with binding commands to button inside datagrid.

Here should be explanation but it doesn't explain everything.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458928.aspx

What should be in classes in namespace Infrastructure?

Can somebody show me a really basic sample of using this?
not just parts of the code...

Answer (score 0):

The Prism **Commanding QuickStart** - included with the Prism drop should provide the simple code example you are looking for.

All data-bindings go against the current DataContext unless specified otherwise.  The DataContext is inherited down the tree of controls unless a control specifically picks a DataContext.

For example your Button might look like this and would look for the SaveCommand on whatever the DataContext has:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand} />
```

Your button could also look like this if you wanted to bind to a command exposed on your classes code-behind:

```
<UserControl x:Name="UserControl">
   ...
    <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand, ElementName=UserControl}"
   ...
</UserControl>
```

Using DelegateCommand is just a way of implementing the ICommand you bind to and that should be visibile in the Prism QuickStart.